# Getting two value from my dll

Tags: c#, dll, windows

```
puplic class Example;
{
   public static int Test(int[] Array, int value1, int value2)
      {
         // here I calculate my value1 and value2 by using my Array
      }
}
```

It is my dll above. Then I want to cal my dll in my windows application below.

```
private void buttonStart_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value1=0, value2=0;
    Example.Test(Array,value1,value2);
}
```

My Array is defined global. In my windows application,I want to call my dll and calculate my new value1 and value2 in dll then change my value1 and value2 which are in windows application with new value1 and value2.

I am new in using dll. I can return one value from my dll by using 'return value1;' but I do not know how I can get two value from my dll.

Is there anybody who knows the way?

Comment: Are you trying to pass by reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out

```
public static int Test(int[] Array, out int value1, out int value2)
```

or

```
public static int Test(int[] Array, ref int value1, ref int value2)
```

See [Passing Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx).